# Spring Security and DerbyDB (javaDB)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, derby

I am on a school project involving Spring MVC, Spring Security and DerbyDB.

I have an issue I can't resolve and I need help, thanks in advance.

Here is the message when I try to log-in with a real user (printed on the web page) :

```
Your login attempt was not successful, try again.

Reason: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select LOGIN, PASSWORD from theaterDB."User" where LOGIN = ?]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Column '3' not found.
```

Here is the message in the console :

```
SQL error codes for 'Apache Derby' found
2013-10-22 16:07:16 [DEBUG] SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator:283 - Unable to translate SQLException with SQL state 'S0022', error code '0, will now try the fallback translator
2013-10-22 16:07:16 [DEBUG] SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator:95 - Extracted SQL state class 'S0' from value 'S0022'
2013-10-22 16:07:16 [DEBUG] UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter:346 - Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select LOGIN, PASSWORD from theaterDB."User" where LOGIN = ?]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Column '3' not found.
2013-10-22 16:07:16 [DEBUG] UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter:347 - Updated SecurityContextHolder to contain null Authentication
```

My datasource bean:

```
   <bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:derby:/home/couty/capDB;create=true" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
   </bean>
```

The spring-security.xml :

```
<http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/welcome*" access="ROLE_USER" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"

                users-by-username-query='select LOGIN, PASSWORD from theaterDB."User" where LOGIN = ?'/>

                <!-- authorities-by-username-query="select u.login, ur.role from User u, UserRole ur where u.id = ur.user_id and u.login =?  " --> 

        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

As you can see :
I'm trying to login while accessing the /welcome page.
The JDBC driver i used is the DERBY one, not the ORACLE. Why ? Because i already had the derby and the oracle seemed to be a pain to catch.. I don't know what does it changes.

Comment: Here's some advice on how to get more information out of your SQLException: http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UnwindExceptionChain

Comment: Hi, thank you, I'm gonna use this in my apps.
But, as the request here is made enterely by Spring Security, I don't know how i should catch the sql Exception...

Comment: Try using the "ij" tool to connect directly to your database and issue the offending SQL statement directly, to see if you get a better error display that gives you more clues. Alternatively, use derby.language.logStatementText=true to get more information in your derby.log

Comment: Thanks I'll try to log the errors.
The fact is my request is good, I tested it with SQL scrapbook and through my code.

If it persists I think I'm gonna code my own authentificationManager

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have to add an additional column "enabled" to query. So something like this - select LOGIN, PASSWORD, enabled from theaterDB."User" where LOGIN = ?.

I had the same issue and this worked in my case ;)